# how to return results not found in data table with html and bootsrap

Tags: javascript, html

I am working a table with HTML and Bootrsap, I have created a function search that display each of filter what I am looking for.
But  in case that I don't found any record on table to display message  .

Comment: Can u show the code or an image to see the display?

Comment: maybe you should have some tag for text and use `display:  None` to hide this message or to hide table. And later you could set again `display: block` to show text back (or to show table)